# wget downloads html file, but I need a fasta file

Tags: wget, ncbi

I have to search NCBI for ID CAA37914 and download the fasta file using wget on ubuntu-18.04 and rename the file to CAA37914.fa.

I looked up the ID and got the following url: https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/protein/CAA37914.1/?report=fasta

I tried the following:

```
wget https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/protein/CAA37914.1/?report=fasta -O CAA37914.fa
```

But that didn't work. What am I doing wrong?

I get a file with html output

edit:

I think I have to do it something like this:

```
wget “link/entrez/eutils/efetch.fcgi?db=nucleotide&id=NM_208885&retype=fasta” -O NP_983532_dna.fa
```

Comment: That URL goes to an HTML page. What did you expect?

Comment: It seems like you would like to download the actual content generated when viewing the data in fasta format? This will not be possible just using wget. You could however download the actual page as html and then use some other tool to parse the actual content of the `viewercontent1 pre` tag.

Comment: https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/sviewer/viewer.cgi?tool=portal&save=file&log$=seqview&db=protein&report=fasta&id=34416&extrafeat=null&conwithfeat=on looks like it produces plain text (option "Send to" - "File").

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out.
This is the answer:

```
wget "http://eutils.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/entrez/eutils/efetch.fcgi?db=nucleotide&id=CAA37914&rettype=fasta" -O CAA37914.fa
```